# Difference Between #include "file.h" and #include <file.h>

Tags: c, c++, header-file

What is the difference between the `#include "file.h"` and the `#include <file.h>`? Surely they mean the exact same thing, because I have a file that has something like this:

```
#include <file1.h>
#include <file2.h>
#include "file3.h"
#include "file3.h"
```

Comment: [What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include “filename”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21593/995714)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has more to do with C and C++ than Unix, and as such belongs to SO.

To answer your question, the `<>` indicates headers in the standard library and `""` the libraries written specifically for the project.

From [the K&R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language):

> Any source line of the form
>
> #include "filename"
>
> or
>
> #include <filename>
>
> is replaced by the contents of the file filename. If the filename is quoted, searching for the file typically begins where the source program was found; if it is not found there, or if the name is enclosed in < and >, searching follows an implementation-defined rule to find the file. An included file may itself contain #include lines